# What structures do we need on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis

Most books, i.e. all I've seen, talk about differentiability of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the structures and associated properties introduced fairly arbitrarily, with very little motivation about why we need those structures.

To be specific, it's not enough to talk about differentiability of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb{R}$, we need to consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and even that's not enough, we need to consider it with an inner product and (hence) a norm to have a notion of nearness for continuity. It's not even enough to consider $\mathbb{R}$ as "the field $\mathbb{R}$", we also need to have an order on the elements of $\mathbb{R}$.

But all books I've seen are sloppy in this regard, and merely talk about $\mathbb{R}^n$ the vector space, with the inner product and norm introduced in a very ad-hoc manner, usually without reference to those structures explicitly, because they are intuitively "obvious".

So, question: For functions between finite dimensional real vector spaces, with is the minimal amount of structure (eg the vector spaces are normed, not just vector spaces)  one needs on those vector spaces in order to have a notion of differentiability? My minimal I mean if you remove one of them, you can no longer have differentiability.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. If $V$ is any real vector space (of finite dimension), it is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$, and $\mathbb R^n$ is already equipped with a notion of differentiablity of functions (which is perhaps the most primitive notion of differentiablity there is!), which we transport to $V$ (along with the topology of $\mathbb R^n$) via any linear isomorphism $V\to\mathbb R^n$. It is worth to remark that the smooth structure defined on $V$ is independent of the choice of isomorphism.

Comment: Check out [Fréchet_derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative). Finite-dimensional real normed spaces are always Banach, and linear transformations between finite-dimensional real normed spaces are always bounded, so several details in its definition may be ignored. The definition of this derivative requires that both the domain and codomain are normed.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Presumably you mean "finite-dimensional", and also, how is the isomorphism canonical?

Comment: @AlexProvost Sure, that's what the OP is talking about. And yes, that word shouldn't be there. =)

Comment: @edm That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $f : V \to W$ is an function between two vectors spaces, the differential (say, at $x$), $L$, is defined as the unique linear application $L : V \to W$ such that $f(y) = f(x) + L(y - x) + g(y - x)$ where there is a constant such that $\lim\limits_{y \to x} \frac{\|g(y - x)\|}{\|y - x\|} = 0$.

Hence you see that a norm is necessary. In fact I think this is sufficient : there is a theory of differential calculus over general Banach spaces.

(of course Banach spaces are also complete but for calculus completeness is very important).

Comment: Never heard of "linear application". And how do you define "smooth function" before you define differentiability?

Comment: A ($k$) -linear application between two ($k$) vectors space is an application $f : V \to W$ such that for every $\lambda, \mu \in k$ and $u,v \in V$ we have $f(\lambda u + \mu v) = \lambda f(u) + \mu f(v)$.
You're right about smooth function it does not make sense, I edited my answer.